# What's the most size-efficient spatial database

Tags: postgis, software-recommendations, spatial-database, mongodb, tile-server

I'm configuring a tile server on Apache Mesos. From all the tutorials I've read, I gathered that PostgreSQL and PostGIS is widely used for this purpose.

I learned that MongoDb and MySQL Server also can be configured for spatial databases (but could not find any tutorial on the same).

My goal is to set up a tile server (which I've done with PostgreSQL) but wanted to know which DB would be the most efficient (w.r.t space and tile rendering speed)?

Comment: Space is cheap, time is expensive. I'd be asking which one is going to take more time to learn, setup and administer. PostGIS extension to PostgreSQL is fairly well documented and has lots of time saving tools so would be my pick **but** if you're not interested so much in saving your time but investigating a technology which may or may not be useful in the future the challenge of other options may be alluring.

Comment: For a tile server I'd check out geoserver. It can integrate with postgres/postgis to serve content from there. It can do caching, time-series, rendering styles etc and is pretty quick.

Comment: Rasdaman  might be a contender for you http://www.rasdaman.com/

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thank you! what you said makes sense.